# Service Broker External activator with Managed Instance

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance

Is Service Broker External activator supported on managed instances? how to notify an external process like Webjob or Azure function? I am trying to avoid creating a CLR to call a webservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service Broker External Activator requires Windows authentication, while Managed Instance supports only SQL and AAD authentication, so I guess that it cannot work.

Also, Service Broker External Activator reacts only on DDL events. If you need to implement notification on data changes you would need to create external app that uses change tracking, query notifications. However, if you need to call some external trigger from SQL engine, I guess that you cannot avoid CLR.